# Colab Google runs code for sometime and disconnects automatically. Not the Captcha problem

Tags: python, tensorflow, socket.io, google-colaboratory

"Recording uncaught error: Error Error: SocketIO is not yet opened" is the exact message on the inspector. Firefox chrome all.

An execution output

Comment: not possible to that extent but let me tell you the disk drive is ok everything is having space still I get this error from nowhere.

Comment: This error could be due to a Connection lost. Please check the internet connection you are using and close - restart Google Colab to check if this error still exists.